# How to convert my video into a file which can be viewed in movie player with ffDiaporama?

Tags: video, convert

Downloaded ffd Diaporama video editting software and cannot convert my video into a file which can be viewed in movie player!

I tried saving with `.avi`, etc., and it just adds the `.ffd` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are saving the project (an XML file with extension `.ffd`). What you need is to "render video", which can be done by clicking the 'Device type', 'Lossless' or the 'Advanced' button from the **Render** tab.

[image: advanced render video dialog box]

Check the corresponding [How-to](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/?page_id=7627) (available in several languages).